# Export to .xlsx

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Could anyone suggest best way to export data to .xlsx format.
1.Dynamically creating sheets.
2.customizing the data in each sheet.
We can't use office web components.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at the [OpenXML SDK 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0).

Related blog articles:

- [Creating an Excel Workbook with the Open XML SDK 2.0](http://blog.stuartwhiteford.com/?p=49) by Stuart Whiteford
- [Document Assembly Solution for SpreadsheetML](http://blogs.msdn.com/brian_jones/archive/2008/11/04/document-assembly-solution-for-spreadsheetml.aspx) by Brian Jones

Comment: OpenXML to write to a .xlsx file?

Comment: @Oscar Mederos: Yes, if you want to be independent of Office and use the full feature-set of Excel generating OpenXML using the OpenXML SDK is a suitable option.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a third-party component like [Aspose Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/file-format-components/aspose.cells-for-.net-and-java/default.aspx) or [XLSIO](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/xlsio/web/default.aspx) (Syncfusion):

> Using Aspose.Cells, developers can
>   easily open and save a multitude of
>   file formats. These include Excel 97 /
>   2000 / XP / 2007 (XLSX),
>   SpreadSheetML, Tab Delimited and CSV
>   documents. Using Aspose.Cells you can
>   also open encrypted Excel files. It is
>   even possible to convert Excel
>   documents into PDF format by using
>   another Aspose product (that is
>   Aspose.Pdf) alongwith Aspose.Cells.

Answer (score 1):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) can generate XLS and XLSX workbooks and includes a comprehensive API for customizing / formatting the data.

You can see the live ASP.NET Excel Reporting samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/excel.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC.

Answer (score 1):

[Excel Package](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/) is an open-source (GPL) component for reading/writing Excel 2007 files. I used it on a small project, and the API is straightforward.

The source code also seems well-organized and easy to get around (if you need to expand functionality or fix minor issues as I did).

You can use either approach (customizing a template or creating everything from scratch). Customizing is much easier if you want the result to look nice.

Answer (score 1):

EPPlus is a .net library that reads and writes Excel 2007/2010 files using the Open Office Xml format (xlsx).

http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Remember also that in many cases a .CSV will do. Excel reads those fine.

You'll only need an XLSX file for Excel-only features like the formatting, multiple worksheets, etc. - and for those, there are a number of existing Excel 1997-2003 generator libraries that make files that'll work with Excel 2007.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com) to export your data as xlsx file. A nice formatting can be set to your report using this library.